# A word to mean escape from a dire situation involving death

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, american-english

When the Sobibór prisoners [escaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobib%C3%B3r_extermination_camp#The_uprising) they were in a dire situation. They could stay in the camp to face certain execution, or revolt. Risking revolt meant they *might* die, but there would be a slim chance of survival.

Looking for a word that means, "possibly die if you do, or definitely die if you don't." There are many synonyms for [dire](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/dire/synonyms) (as in a *dire escape*), but none imply a choice with death as a consequence one way and uncertain death the other.

This situation also comes up a lot in (spoiler alert!) [movies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYhtQcncT2k) (especially man vs. nature): if you don't try, you die.

An example usage:

"The Sobibór prisoners faced a *???* escape."

What word can replace *???*, as per the implied outcome of death vs. possible death?

For example, the phrase "dilemma of a hopelessly moribund escape" gets close, but is quite wordy and doesn't capture the die/might die context.

Answer (score 2):

[***Life-and-death***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/life-and-death?q=life+and+death) is a broadly used adjective:

> Deciding whether someone lives or dies; vitally important: ‘heart
>   surgeons deal with life-and-death situations on a daily basis’

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

[***A matter of life and death***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/matter_of_life_and_death)

> Something whose outcome could result in either someone's survival or
>   their death

[Wiktionary]

[***Critical***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/critical) could be used:

> (Of a situation or problem) having the potential to become disastrous;
>   at a point of crisis:

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: @DaveJarvis I understand your point. When a doctor says, "He is in a critical condition," he means he might be dead soon. There is a connotation of death in "critical".

Answer (score 0):

*The Sobibór prisoners faced a **deadly** dilemma*

> **DEADLY**
>
> : causing or able to cause death
>   [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deadly)
>
> *The prisoners faced a deadly dilemma* [Rules and Rights in the Middle East](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=v3gIb-oSkXQC&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=%22prisoners+faced+a+deadly+dilemma%22&source=bl&ots=zz-dhpn4Tw&sig=Y64qVKaOzuB-D48qrTrNcrB_uPI&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMIx5DaseDVyAIVylgUCh0LFg5p)

Answer (score 0):

I find it difficult to believe there will be a single word for what you want. The best I can come up with is do-or-die.

*The Sobibór prisoners faced a do-or-die escape.*

> **do or die**
>
> said when you are in a ​situation in which you must take a ​big ​risk
>   in ​order to ​avoid ​failure
>
> [Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do-or-die)

Here are some others:

**[last-gasp](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=last%20gasp%20meaning)**
**last-chance**
**[last-resort](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=last%20resort%20definition)**

EDIT

I suppose the word [desperate](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=desperate%20meaning) is pretty close.